# Make install in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to build a docker image, via a dockerfile.

There is one particular application, i would like the dockerfile to have.

The way i install this application is i have some cmake files, and i use `make, install`.

I want to have this functionality inside the dockefile. In other words, when the dockerfile is built, i want to have the application already installed in my image.

How do i handle the file management thing in the dockerfile?

I know that when i deal with the `RUN` command, i can mount filesystems, from the docker host to the docker image. But i am not exactly interested in that now, since the files that the dockerfile will use, are only for building the application, and nothing else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically in your `Dockerfile` you would:

1. `COPY` your source files into your image.
2. Install your necessary tools (`make`, etc...).
3. `RUN` make to build and install your application.

A basic Dockerfile might be:

```
FROM ubuntu

# Copy your source file directory into /app
COPY path/to/source /app/

# Install make
RUN apt update && apt install -y make

# Change to /app
WORKDIR /app

# run make
RUN make install
```

### Example

As a simple example lets say I have this makefile that builds and installs an application called `sayhi`:

```
install:
        echo -n "#!/bin/bash\necho hello world" >> /usr/local/bin/sayhi
        chmod +x /usr/local/bin/sayhi
```

Using this Dockerfile in the same directory, I build my image using `docker build --tag sayhi .`

```
FROM ubuntu

COPY . /app/

RUN apt update && apt install -y make

WORKDIR /app

RUN make install

# Set the default command to run my application
CMD ["sayhi"]
```

Then I can run my docker container like so:

```
$ docker run sayhi
hello world
```

Comment: It's also worth using a multi-layer build where you can copy over the built files, as there's no need for the source/object debris to be in the final container.